# No wifi after rebooting

Tags: iwlwifi

After rebooting my Wifi stopped working. I have tried to reboot a couple of times but it seems to be not very succesful.

I have tried to troubleshoot the problem `dmesg |grep iwl`. I can confirm my

```
[   21.745425] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   21.745426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   21.745717] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   21.926926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   21.934264] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   21.934862] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   22.939087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[   23.187417] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   23.187437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   23.187446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9404F365 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   23.187454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   23.187462] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0513382C | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   23.187470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   23.187479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE1AEB4EE | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   23.187487] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x890E40BF | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   23.187495] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x12201994 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   23.187504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3974E5B4 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   23.187512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   23.187553] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   23.187627] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   23.187700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   23.187877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[   23.187879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   23.191529] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   23.203122] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

The hardware I am using  is

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a4]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

39:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:1325]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Any hints on how to approach?

Kind regards
Erik

Comment: is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: No, single boot

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? Which release?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.

I installed a new driver by following the instructions of the [kernel wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi).

After rebooting everything works fine